# Is cors not allowed on chrome by default even if server has implemented cors?

Tags: google-chrome, cors

I'm developing a web application. During development, I want my locally hosted application can send xmlhttprequest to another domain.

I googled around, a lot of materials say to allow cors on chrome, I need to use the `--disable-web-security` option. Any server needs to implement the response header: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

Does it mean even if a server has implemented cors, normal chrome user still won't be able to send cross origin request because the --disable-web-security is not enabled?

If that's the case, then what's the point for server to implement cors? normal user they won't know and turn on --disable-web-security option.

Comment: It is allowed on chrome.
Refer this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource/28848096#28848096

Comment: I'm still unclear, do you mean --disable-web-security is not needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After did some testing, I have got my answer.
Most of the online materials or blogs are not clear about this point, you can send cross origin request by:

1. either has the server implement cors, i.e. the response header needs to have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`
2. or you `--disable-web-security` your chrome browser for convenience

So you only need to have one of above for cross origin request to work. It's **NOT** necessary to both ensure the server implemented cors and disable web security of your web browser.